# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using LISP for constraint satisfaction in 3D space

Tags: optimization, programming-languages, lisp, prolog

We are currently working on developing a 3D modeling software that allows designers to set spatial constraints to models. The computer then should generate a 3D mesh conforming to these constraints.

Why should or shouldn't we use Lisp for the constraint satisfaction part? Will Prolog environment be any better? Or should we stick to C/C++ libraries?

One requirement we have is that we want to use the Unity Game Engine as it has a lot of 3D tools built in

Comment: Do you like lisp? Or do you have knowledge about lisp? That's the reason why you should or not use it. Use tools you know. Or you can invest your time to learn different tools, but if you are able to use your old, why should you?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a question which will only receive opinion based answer's. A question you should ask yourself is if the constraint part is really that complex that it is worth to use a different programming language. Unity itself offers a C# API [1] and I would therefore stick with that.

[1] https://unity3d.com/programming-in-unity